# How to deploy correctly an nextjs application?

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, pre-rendering

> next build
> Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
> This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
> You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
> https://nextjs.org/telemetry
> ▲ Next.js 14.0.2
> Creating an optimized production build ...
> ✓ Compiled successfully
> Linting and checking validity of types ...
> Collecting page data ...
> Generating static pages (0/11) ...

Generating static pages (2/11)

Generating static pages (5/11)

Generating static pages (7/11)

Generating static pages (8/11)
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
}
}
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
}
}
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
}
}
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
}
}
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3000
}
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /page: /

✓ Generating static pages (11/11)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I try to change environement, and it didn't work

Comment: The question does not contain actionable items. The logs without the code or snippets of code that generated them are simply not helpful. Please read more on https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example